# How those undocumented ANSI codes work

Tags: linux, terminal, encoding, ansi

I found [gnu head ANSI art](https://www.gnu.org/graphics/agnuheadterm-xterm.txt) (that show up in alsmot grayscale on Cygwin terminal)

[image]

and it have undocumented ANSI CSI SGR numbers like:

```
[38;5;243m
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_codes) say that the numbers are up to 109. What those 234 do? Are those codes documetation somewere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These codes are used for setting 8-bits colors codes in xterm.

The prefix is `[38;5;` and `243m` the color code. That's what is written in Wikipedia :

> 38 : Set xterm-256 text color

You can find more details in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15712766/2536143)